# How to Simulate workload

Tags: java, python, perl, workload

I have to write a program (perl , python or java) to simulate workload on our server such that it takes 2 arguments :

1. Memory
2. Time

And based on these arguments it should start a process that consumes the specified amount of memory for specified amount of time.Max value of memory can be as high as 50-100GB and Time can be upto 12-24 hrs.

I cannot use fork or multi threads, this process should be a single thread and should continuously do operations (like Integer / Floating point etc). I don't want to do any I/O operations also.

The simplest way I could think of was:

```
 1. while(timeSpent < timeLimit || memoryConsumed < memorySpecified){
 2.           if(memoryConsumed < ){
 3.                Add random number to ArrayList 
 4.           }else{
 5.                Multiply all numbers (Do some exception handling to prevent this from overflowing) 
 6.           }
 7. }
```

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: :) no I graduated one year back. I am actually writing this for doing stress testing for my code on server. I have an option of using something like stress http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/  but later I know I would need things that stress doenot provide so wanted to start with something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the utility stress weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress ... though tweaked it a bit to extend the features that I wanted..

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this python code suit your needs?

```
import argparse
import datetime

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Consume memory and time.")
    parser.add_argument('memory', metavar = 'M', type=int, help = "memory (in megabytes) to consume")
    parser.add_argument('time', metavar = 'H', type=int, help = "time (in hours) to consume")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    data = bytearray(args.memory * 1000000)
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    finish = now + datetime.timedelta(hours = args.time)
    while now < finish:
        for i in xrange(args.memory * 1000000):
             data[i] = now.second
        now = datetime.datetime.today()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems reasonable, at least for a first step. There are however many little details to get right:

- You say you don't want to do I/O, and that is fine, however in the 
  allocation of 50-100 GB in a modern machine you will do I/O whether you
  want it or not (by way of page faults), so you may want to redefine
  your spec there.
- Also, take into account the granularity of your "objects", many
  scientific computing apps cannot get by the "many small objects"
  paradigm. You many want to have some parameter to balance between
  "many small objects" and "few large objects".
- Also, by multiplying or adding or something all datapoints in your
  container you may generate a sequence of page faults that may
  easily be  predicted by the OS, and therefore unrealistic in the
  real world, you may want to add some randomness in the way you
  traverse it.

It is a more subtle problem than it seems, and you many want to start simple and perhaps even with standard tests like: SETI or a raytracer.